# Creating a parameterized java class with a string based parameter

Tags: java, reflection

Is is possible to create an instance of a parameterized class with a string based parameter like this  :

```
String aType = "MyType";
AFoobarType<aType> aClassInstance = new AFoobarType<aType>(){
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: No, it is not. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you know the set of classes which you might create, a Switch statement may be your solution.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This question was just out of curiosity. I'm just trying to see how dynamic could be a class creation. Even with reflection it's still impossible to achieve ?

Comment: Yes. Generics are a compile time concept. Reflection operates at runtime.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm trying to do my stuff at runtime.

Comment: But generics don't work at runtime. Their only benefit is that the compiler can catch type incompatibilities at compile time. The types are erased at runtime.